# How to create custom datasource for each session

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I would like to create a stateless bean in Spring boot which enable user to connect to a specific database, so I started with this code, but i'm still new with spring boot.

```
@Bean
@Primary 
public DataSource helloDataSource() {

    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .username("myUsername")
            .password("myPassword")
            .driverClassName("myDBDriver")
            .build();
}
```

So what is the best way to follow to make this code work and connect to any database ( Also remote Database )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways that this could be done. One of my preferred way is to provide configuration of data sources via properties file. Here is a sample property file for postgresql:

```
pg.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db-server-bar:5432/app-db
pg.datasource.username=root
pg.datasource.password=toor
pg.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Now you can create configuration class for each datasource:

```
public class BarDbConfig {

  @Bean(name = "pgDataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "pg.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "barEntityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
  barEntityManagerFactory(
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
    @Qualifier("pgDataSource") DataSource dataSource
  ) {
    return
      builder
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages("com.app.domain")
        .persistenceUnit("pg")
        .build();
  }
}
```

For a detailed tutorial, you can refer to [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7).

There can also be situations where you would like to switch databases at runtime. In which case, you can use something called `AbstractRoutingDataSource`. A detailed tutorial on how to use this feature can be found at [Spring's official blog site](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/).